# How can I communicate with a backgrounded Python instance?

Tags: python, linux, testing, vim, background-process

#### Environment preamble:

I write Python code in Vim for Maya on Linux. I'm using nose for test discovery and execution, and I'm using its attribute plugin to decorate Maya-only test classes. I have mappings in Vim to run the non-Maya tests in regular Python, and the Maya tests through Maya's `mayapy` executable, which gives me access to the scene, and the maya.cmds module.

#### Actual problem:

`mayapy` takes 6 seconds to start up every time I hit my in-Maya tests Vim mapping. It gets really tedious. The non-Maya tests happen as fast as I can hit their mapping. It's helped me abstract more away from Maya, to avoid that tiny, all-day pain, but I'd still like it gone. 6 seconds starts to feel like a long time. There are tricks for working asynchronously in Vim, but I don't like to move ahead without seeing if my tests passed. I've asked Autodesk (makers of Maya), and they say there's no way around the startup time.

#### Question:

What I *think* I want is to fire up `mayapy` in the background, and then when I hit my Vim mapping, have it connect to the waiting Python instance and call the `nose.run()` command. I feel like `mkfifo` is the way to go, but I'm unsure of the particulars. How can I do this (through `mkfifo` or otherwise)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming mayapy is like a repl and you can hit commands on to it like the mentioned `nose.run()`. If that is the case, I would recommend using the vim plugin [tslime](https://github.com/kikijump/tslime.vim) which allows you to be able to send stuff from a vim buffer to another tmux pane / window.

Comment: This is a really clever solution. I was hoping to do with nothing more than Vim and the shell, but my thoughts on mkfifo haven't borne fruit, and I can't see another way. Named pipes block, and they're not intended to pause input and wait for more; they're meant for connecting inputs and outputs, which doesn't match this problem. They're are a few more details to work out, but I've already gotten tests in tmux shells to work with send-keys, and I did end my question with "or otherwise," so this is a valid (and good) answer. Accepted. Thanks!